# jQuery backbone search output error

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

So. I'm having a problem with backbone search output.
When I search something, everything works fine and outputs: **Result: test**
Now... When I decide to search something else, it will output it as **Result: testResult: test2** which is incorrect..
Also I have online demo http://jsbin.com/ogabam/3
And thank you.

index:

```
<form name="input" action="" method="get">
Search: <input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('form').submit(function() {
    var form_data = ($(this).serialize());
    window.location.hash = form_data.replace('=','/');
    return false;
});
</script>
```

main:

```
(function() {

window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Router: {}
};

App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        'show/:id': 'show',
        'search/:query': 'search',
        '*other': 'default'
    },

    index: function() {
        $(document.body).append("");
    },

    show: function(id) {
        $(document.body).append(id);
    },

    search: function(query) {
        $(document.body).append("Result: " + query);
    }

});

new App.Router();
Backbone.history.start();

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `div` as a placeholder of the result and just replace the text with the result.

(If you want to use `append` you can use [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) before)

working example: http://jsbin.com/ogabam/4/